# JAXB unmarshalling - XML attribute to Java field

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use the JAXB unmarshalling to covert the following XML into Java class, but I could not find a way to translate XML attribute like "zipCode" into java field "zipCode". How can I achieve this in JAXB?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<datacollection id="amazonOrder">
    <table name="AmazonOrderTable">
        <row>
            <field name="zipCode">20170</field>
            <field name="customerLastName">DE</field>
            <field name="state">VA</field>            
            <field name="city">COMMERCE CITY</field>
            <field name="serialNumber">818243CX601252Y</field>
            <field name="homePhone">3032885239</field>
            <field name="customerFirstName">ROGER</field>
            <field name="customerAddress">13390 E 106TH PL</field>
        </row>
    </table>
</datacollection>
```

```java
public class CustomerInfo {

protected String customerAddress;
protected String customerFirstName;
protected String customerLastName;
protected String serialNumber;
protected String zipCode;    
protected String city;

public String getCustomerAddress() {
    return customerAddress;
}

public void setCustomerAddress(String customerAddress) {
    this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
}

public String getCustomerFirstName() {
    return customerFirstName;
}

public void setCustomerFirstName(String customerFirstName) {
    this.customerFirstName = customerFirstName;
}

public String getCustomerLastName() {
    return customerLastName;
}

public void setCustomerLastName(String customerLastName) {
    this.customerLastName = customerLastName;
}

public String getSerialNumber() {
    return serialNumber;
}

public void setSerialNumber(String serialNumber) {
    this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
}

public String getZipCode() {
    return zipCode;
}

public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post your unmarshalling code? Also, is your XML supposed to contain `zipcode`, not `zipCode`?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the `@XmlElement(name = "zipcode")` annotation to your `getZipCode()` and `setZipCode()` methods.

Comment: Thanks Rosini, next question is I want to avoid the mapping for following tags from xml and all the <field> elements should get translated to java class, how can I achieve this ? 

    <datacollection id="amazonOrder">
    <table name="AmazonOrderTable">
    <row>

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking.

Comment: I want to convert the following into java object, the other tags like "datacollection ", "table" , "row" should be avoided

<field name="zipCode">20170</field>
            <field name="customerLastName">DE</field>
            <field name="state">VA</field>            
            <field name="city">COMMERCE CITY</field>
            <field name="serialNumber">818243CX601252Y</field>
            <field name="homePhone">3032885239</field>
            <field name="customerFirstName">ROGER</field>
            <field name="customerAddress">13390 E 106TH PL</field>

Comment: You should ask this in a new question, but generally in XML you do something like this: `<CustomerInfo><zipCode>20170</zipCode><city>COMMERCE CITY</city>...</CustomerInfo>`

Comment: XML is coming from another source where I don't have any control.

Answer (score 0):

In you example, "zipCode" is not an attribute.  It is a value of the "name" attribute.  JAXB will turn elements and attributes into fields when you generate JAXB classes, but the values are assigned to the fields, not used for naming fields.